# I want to remove the quantity option from wishlist which shows on the customer dashboard in the wishlist section Magento 1.9 (Intenso theme)

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to remove the option of quantity from the wishlist section found on the customer dashboard. As we a eCommerce company which have products with only 1 quantity.

```
<?php if (($this->getAddToCartQty($item) * 1) < 10): ?>
            <select class="simulate-change" name="qty[<?php echo $item->getId() ?>]" id="qty[<?php echo $item->getId() ?>]">
                <?php for ($i=1; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"<?php if (($this->getAddToCartQty($item) * 1) == $i): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $i ?></option>
                <?php endfor; ?>
                <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go `/app/design/frontend/Your Theme Package/YOur Theme/template/wishlist/item/column/quantity.phtml` file and just comment below line:

```
    <?php /*if (($this->getAddToCartQty($item) * 1) < 10): ?>
            <select class="simulate-change" name="qty[<?php echo $item->getId() ?>]" id="qty[<?php echo $item->getId() ?>]">
                <?php for ($i=1; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"<?php if (($this->getAddToCartQty($item) * 1) == $i): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $i ?></option>
                <?php endfor; ?>
                <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select>
    <?php endif;*/?>
```

Comment: the same code is already there.. do i have to do any changes there ?

Comment: Yes you have to add php comment line "/* */" before if condition.

Comment: i did, but its still showing the quantity dropdown box on the customer dashboard. i tried clearing cache also.

Comment: You are trying in Account Dashboard> Wishlist section?

Comment: yes i want to remove it from there, as whenever anyone adds products on to his wishlist. On his account dashboard >Wishlist section he see the products and right side there is a option quantity with a dropdown of 1 to 10+ .

Comment: Please check with enable template path hint for actually which phtml file called for wishlist. Thanks.

Comment: frontend/intenso/default/template/wishlist/item/column/cart.phtml

Comment: frontend/intenso/default/template/wishlist/item/column/quantity.phtml. You have to check in quantity.phtml file not in cart.phtml file.

Comment: there are only 3 files in that folder cart.phtml, info.phtml & remove.phtml

Comment: Okay. Then you have to copy magento base or rwd theme's  /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/wishlist/item/column/quantity.phtml file and put into your intenso theme. Then do modification.

Comment: i found the code in cart file.. " <?php if (($this->getAddToCartQty($item) * 1) < 10): ?>
            <select class="simulate-change" name="qty[<?php echo $item->getId() ?>]" id="qty[<?php echo $item->getId() ?>]">
                <?php for ($i=1; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"<?php if (($this->getAddToCartQty($item) * 1) == $i): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $i ?></option>
                <?php endfor; ?>
                <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select>"  now how can i do changes in this

Comment: Have you tried with comment that if condition?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: i tried adding /* and */ but it removed the dropdown option for quantity but still the box was there. maybe i didn't do it right, if you can help me out exactly what to do.

Comment: You have to comment whole html part before set in select tag.

Comment: i tried you above code but it shows syntax error on line 42 which is <?php endif; ?>

Comment: Yes. Please add your whole part of quantity section with html section in your question.

Comment: i found it bro, thnx for help :D